# How do I debug why a Power Automate Desktop Flow freezes?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, power-automate-desktop

As I am running my Power Automate Desktop flow using a for loop, the process freezes, but there is no pattern I can figure out yet. It froze after processing over 750 Active Directory on-premise updates, and it froze after only 100 Active Directory updates. Where it freezes is during execution of a PowerShell script action that as you can hopefully tell is executing a PowerShell script. The process timer is still running, but the process stops. The flow does not show any errors and I can't find any logs that show an error. The account has access to update Active Directory.

I tried looking for errors returned from the flow process and logs, but there are no errors returned and I can't find logs that show anything valuable.

So, I need to figure out a way to debug the flow to get a better idea why it is freezing.

Edit:

PowerShell 7.0 is installed on the machine running Power Automate Desktop.

The PowerShell script being executed WITHIN Power Automate Desktop using the Run PowerShell Script action where it froze is below. It is updating an Active Directory user's Title. After processing many of the same updates to the Title for other users the process freezes.

```
Set-ADUser -Identity %CurrentItem['SamAccountName']% -Title "%CurrentItem['NewValue']%"
```

Comment: The question definitely needs more debugging details, eg about the script that performs the task, Powershell version etc. Is it anything you programmed or off the shelf software?

Comment: @yacc - I added more info after the "Edit:" line. As far as debugging, that's what I'm trying to figure out, what type of debugging I can ADD to the Power Automate Desktop flow to help figure out why it freezes. There is nothing in the output variable from the Run PowerShell Script action. The "CurrentItem" array in the PowerShell script does show me the row where it is freezing. The values in that array row are not causing any issues because the values in each element are the same type of values previously processed successfully before freezing. I have already listed the software I am using.